# Two sequences are subsequences of one another, one converges. Are they the same?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ converge to a. Let $b_n$ be a subsequence of $a_n$ and $a_n$ be a subsequence of $b_n$. Are they the same?

I've tried showing they are by contradiction, the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem seems relevant but I can't see where. I can't see any counter example but there seems to be some pattern to why examples fail but I can't see it.

Removing the restriction of $a_n$ converging seems to allow for counter examples which all seem to alternate, if I could prove that they all alternate then it would be done as alternating series don't converge.

Hints would be most welcome!

Comment: Your formal definition of subsequence?

Comment: a_k = b_(n (k)) where n is strictly increasing but I'm not sure how that helps, trying to show that n(k)=k seems a logical way forward but how one would attempt this is currently beyond me!

Comment: Trivialy $n(k)\ge k$. take the minimum $k_0$ s.t. $n(k_0)>k_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $a_1 \ne b_1$. Since $a_n$ is a subsequence of $b_n$, there exists a $c_1>1$ s.t. $a_1=b_{c_1}$. For each $i=\{1,...,c_1\}$ there exists $n_i>i$ s.t. $a_{n_i}=b_i$, because $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$. Let $c_2=n_{c_1}$. Now, for each $i=\{1,...,c_2\}$ there exists $n_i>i$ s.t. $b_{n_i}=a_i$. Let $c_3=n_{c_2}$. And so on.

Note that $1<c_1<c_2<c_3<...$ and also that $a_1=b_{c_1}=b_{c_3}=...$.
So $b_n$ has a convergent subsequence with limit $a_1$.

Similarly (starting at $b_1$) we get that $b_n$ has a convergent subsequence with limit $b_1$. That contradicts $a_1 \ne b_1$, since $b_n$ is convergent as well. So we have $a_1=b_1$.

Now considering the sequences starting at $a_2$ and $b_2$ and so on, we get that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks but why does $a_1=b_{c_3}$?

Comment: @Max because $a_1=b_{c_1}=a_{c_2}=b_{c_3}$

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but why should there be an $a_{n_i}=b_i$?

Comment: @Max Well, we know that $b_n$ is a subsequence of $a_n$. So by definition there exists an increasing sequence $n_i$ s.t. $a_{n_i}=b_i$. And since $a_1 \ne b_1$, $n_1>1$, $n_2>n_1>1$ so $n_2>2$, etc. so $n_i>i$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I understand it all now, thank you so much!

Comment: Just out of interest what made you think of this? Analysis can seem like rabbits out of hats a lot of the time!

Comment: @Max Yes, I agree. Here I tried to create a counterexample with $a_1 \ne b_1$, and noticed that the numbers have to reappear everytime, because both sequences are subsequences of each other. So the sequences can't converge to anything else than to the initial numbers.

Comment: So you take the assumption and see what must be the case given the assumption. Then aim for a contradiction from there given what your intuition tells you?

Comment: @Max Yes, that's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition** A sequence $b_n$ is said to be a *subsequence* of a sequence $a_n$ iff there exists a strictly increasing function $\phi\ :\ \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $b_n=a_{\phi\left(n\right)}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.


**Proof** Let $a_n,b_n$ be a subsequence of each other. Then, there exist strictly increasing functions $\phi,\varphi\ :\ \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n=b_{\phi(n)}$ and $b_n=a_{\varphi(n)}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$a_n=b_{\phi(n)}=a_{\varphi(\phi(n))} \ \mathrm{and}\  b_n=a_{\varphi(n)}=b_{\phi(\varphi(n))}.$$
From this, we get $\varphi\circ\phi=I=\phi\circ\varphi$; therefore we write $\varphi=\phi^{-1}$. What this says to us is that the functions $\varphi$ and $\phi$ are bijective.


Assume that $\varphi$ is not the identity function on $\mathbb{N}$, that is, there exists a natural number, say $n_0$, such that $\varphi(n_0)\neq n_0$. Set $\mathbb{N}_x=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ n<x\}$. It follows from $\varphi(n_0)\neq n_0$ that the sets $\mathbb{N}_{n_0}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{\varphi(n_0)}$ have finite but different cardinalities. It is well-known that the function $\varphi^*\ :\ \mathbb{N}_{n_0}\rightarrow\varphi(\mathbb{N}_{n_0})$ defined by
$$\varphi^*(n)=\varphi(n)\mathrm{\ for\ each\ }n\in\mathbb{N_{n_0}}$$ is bijective. Since the function $\varphi$ is a strictly increasing,  we have \begin{array}{rcl}
\varphi(\mathbb{N}_{n_0})&=&\{\varphi(n)\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ n<n_0\}\\
&=&\{\varphi(n)\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ \varphi(n)<\varphi(n_0)\}\\
&=&\mathbb{N}_{\varphi(n_0)}
\end{array} which contradicts the sets $\mathbb{N}_{n_0}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{\varphi(n_0)}$ having finite but different cardinalities. Thus, $\varphi=I$ and so $(a_n)=(b_n)$.